# Binance API Java - Stop-Limit Orders?

Tags: java, api, binance

I have downloaded the [binance API for Java](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api) and I am trying to figure out how to make a new stop-limit order. I have gone in the `NewOrder` class and added a constructor which takes the stop price parameter and a method for creating a stop-limit-sell order.

```
public NewOrder(String symbol, OrderSide side, OrderType type, TimeInForce timeInForce, String quantity, String Price, String stopPrice){
  this(symbol, side, type, timeInForce, quantity);
  this.price=price;
  this.stopPrice=stopPrice;
}

 public static NewOrder stopLimitSell(String symbol, TimeInForce timeInForce, String quantity, String price, String stopPrice){
  return new NewOrder(symbol, OrderSide.SELL, OrderType.STOP_LOSS_LIMIT, timeInForce, quantity, price, stopPrice);
}
```

This is the line of code which is supposed to create the stop limit order

```
client.newOrder(stopLimitBuy("BTCUSDT", TimeInForce.GTC, "0.035375", "5000","4999"));
```

The following error comes up:

> Exception in thread "main" com.binance.api.client.exception.BinanceApiException: Mandatory parameter 'price' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed.

Can someone please direct me in the right direction? What is the way to create a stop-limit order for binance in Java? I cannot find anything...

Comment: In the first piece of code you show a `stopLimitSell()` order and then in the second piece you have a `stopLimitBuy()` call. Is this correct?

Comment: It should be. Binance has a Stop-Limit buying and selling function on their website. There seem to be custom orders available for python and php I just can't find it for Java anywhere....

Comment: I couldn't find the `stopLimitBuy()` method in the Java API. Do you know where it is? We have to look at that code and try to understand how it expects the `price` parameter to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

Create the NewOrder object as a default limit sell order, then add the stop price  (i.e, the trigger value) using NewOrder.stopPrice().

Comment: When you say usuall order, do you mean a limit order?

Comment: Yes. Just improved the answer based on your comment.